# Can not build, get error: No overload for'Form1_Load' matches delegate 'Event Handler

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a program that when i press F, it waits a few seconds then presses Enter. But i get an error saying

> No overload for'Form1_Load' matches delegate 'Event Handler

Here is my Form1.Designer.cs:

```
namespace csgossprogram
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 114);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 264);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
}
```

And here is my code for Form1.cs

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace csgossprogram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("~");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`, not `private void Form1_Load(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`.

`Form.Load` event [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Form.Load` event in this manner has no any point. It is invoked when form loads and there is no key to check if it is F. That's also why `Form.Load` expects handler with `Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` signature.

To do what you wanted you should use `Form.KeyDown` or `Form.KeyUp` event:
1. Rename `Form1_Load` to `Form1_KeyDown` or `Form1_KeyUp`, depending what you have chosen to use. This is optional but it's better to do it so you keep naming consistent.
2. Instead: `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);` use either `this.Load += this.Form1_KeyDown;` or `this.Load += this.Form1_KeyUp;` depending on event you have chosen.

Note, you don't have to use constructor for delegate. Just write method name after `+=` (you can omit `this`, too).